# Is there a utility to manipulate CSS size values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before I try to build something, I would like to know if there is something like this out there? A utility to manipulate css size strings (like "50%", "50px", etc). I am using CssSize as an example:

```
var ht1 = new CssSize("100px");
var ht2 = new CssSize("50px");

var h3 = ht2 - h1;
var val = h3.toString(); // "50px"

var isFixdSiz = h3.isFixedSize(); // true

----

var ht1 = new CssSize("100%");
var ht2 = new CssSize("40%");

var h3 = ht2 - h1; // Similarly a + equivalent.
var val = h3.toString(); // "60%"

var isPercSiz = h3.isPercSize(); // true

----

var isPerc = CssSize.IsPerc("50%"); // true
isPerc = CssSize.IsPerc("50"); // false
isPerc = CssSize.IsPerc("abcd"); // false
isFixed = CssSize.IsFixed("50px"); // true
```

Comment: What about CSS `calc()`? I'm sure there's a jQuery plug-in.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve. What is the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have done heavy work in custom page template manipulation within the browser  and can not see a use case for most of this. What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: So, in my application the heights of the divs will be defined in the database. Let us say there are 2 divs one below the other. If the first div's height is set as 60% in the database, and the 2nd div's height is not set, then I have to assign it 40%. Which means I have to do some arithmatics with the % strings. Hopefully this makes sense.